# Simple autoencoder keeping constant tensor as predict in keras

Tags: python, keras

I'm new in keras and deep learning field. In fact, I want  to make a dense vector for each document in my data so that i built a simple autoencoder using keras library.
The input data are normalized using Word2vec with 200 as embedding size and all features are between -1 and 1. I prepared a 3D tensor that contains 137 samples (number of document) with 469 columns (maximum numbers of words) and the third dimension is the embedding size.I used mse loss function and GRU as recurrent neural network. I am having the same vector for all documents as the autoencoder prediction output while loss start with a very low value and  became constant after a few number of epochs.
I tried different number of epochs but I got the same thing. I tried also to change the batch size but no change. Can any one help me find the problem please.

```
input = Input(shape=(469,200))

encoder = GRU(120,activation='sigmoid',dropout=0.2)(input)

neck = Dense(20)(encoder)

decoder1 = RepeatVector(469)(neck)

decoder1 = GRU(120,return_sequences=True,activation='sigmoid',dropout=0.2)(decoder1)

decoder1 = TimeDistributed(Dense(200,activation='tanh'))(decoder1)

model = Model(inputs=input, outputs=decoder1)

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')

history = model.fit(x_train, x_train,validation_data=(x_test,x_test) ,epochs=10, batch_size=8)
```

this is the input data "x_train" :

[image: this is the input data "x_train" :]

print(model.predict(x_train)) return this values (same vectors):

[image: print(model.predict(x_train)) return this values (same vectors):]

[image: loss]

[image: loss1]
[image: loss2]
[image: loss]

Why "model.predict(x_train)" return the same vector for the 137 samples ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Don't understand what you mean by the same vector. The values are different..?!